# ShareLaTeX timeout: lstlisting doesn't work

Tags: beamer, listings, sharelatex

I created a new document using the default presentation template – `simple-beaver`. Then I added the following:

- `\usepackage{listings}` at the top of the file right after `\documentclass{beamer}` declaration
- a new frame:

  ```
  \section{Some Code}
    \begin{frame}{Code}
      \begin{lstlisting}
        print "Hello world"
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{frame}
  ```

When I press Recompile sharelatex throws time out error. Any ideas how can I make the listings package work in sharelatex presentation?

Comment: Your beamer frame needs to be declared fragile.

Comment: Can you tell us the error?

Comment: http://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/2011/02/20/why-latex-beamer-needs-fragile-when-using-verbatim/

Comment: aka use `\begin{frame}[fragile]{Code}`

Comment: @daleif thank you, it works! I wish they put it in their [docs](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_listing).

Comment: @ScottSeidman thank you for the link to the explanation!

Comment: Well, as the user of `beamer` you should read the beamer manual. ShareLaTeX has written som nice docs, but they cannot cover everything